# Mysql`s SUBSTRING_INDEX equivalent in postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psql

I am basically trying to replicate functionality I know exists in MySQL. In MySQL it would look like:

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.url, 'selection=', -1)
```

How do I replicate this in PSQL?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How do I do the same thing PSQL...

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of   'selection=' delimiters in that column?

Comment: there will be either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT split_part(p.url, 'selection=', 2)...
```

Comment: This only works for positive numbers, not negative numbers like in the OP. To select the last field, for example, use `reverse(split_part(reverse(p.url), 'selection=', 1))`.