# Translating SUBSTRING_INDEX() in MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

There are a number of question related to this and the answer is to use `split_part()`. For example:

[emulating MySQL's substring_index() in PGSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230584/emulating-mysqls-substring-index-in-pgsql)

[Mysql`s SUBSTRING_INDEX equivalent in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364503/mysqls-substring-index-equivalent-in-postgresql)

I'm not getting the same behavior, however. I'm trying to figure out how to get the following functionality in Postgres.

If you have a string that looks like:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| string                                   |
+------------------------------------------+
| A_123, B_123, C_123, D_123, E_123, F_123 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL will return the following with the given statement:

```
mysql> select SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 4) AS test FROM tbl;
+----------------------------+
| test                       |
+----------------------------+
| A_123, B_123, C_123, D_123 |
+----------------------------+
```

PostgreSQL will return the following with the given statement:

```
mysql> select split_part(string, ',', 4) AS test FROM tbl;
+-------+
| test  |
+-------+
| D_123 |
+-------+
```

Is there a similar function or just implementing a function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834099/3123109)?

Comment: Do you have a chance to fix your data model during the migration and store the data in a properly normalized way?

Comment: I don't see any other solution that writing your own function. Or use something like `array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(string, '\s*,\s'))[:4], ', ')` - An alternative might be to convert this to a real array (if you do need to keep this de-normalized) and access array slices.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, that (the regex expression) returned the desired result! When you get a chance, can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name suggested in the comments, this had the desired result:

```
array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(string, '\s*,\s'))[:4], ', ')
```